# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword not authorizing user on sign in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created a system where a user signs up, and once they've successfully signed up, other information they've filled out in the form is supposed to get added to a node with their user ID in the database.

In my createUserWithEmailAndPassword `.then()` callback, I've added a function that is supposed to write to the database. However, upon signing up, the database write always threw `permission denied` errors. I decided to check the values in the firebase.auth().currentUser to make sure the new user was actually signed in, and they were.

When I added the same database write function to the firebase sign-in callback, it worked.

Here's my code; does anyone have any idea why the authentication isn't valid?

```
//Declared above the createUser function
function logUser(user, signUpPhoneNumber, department){
      database.ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
       phone: signUpPhoneNumber,
       department: department
     });
}

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){

        console.log("Email: " +firebase.auth().currentUser.email) //this prints the correct currentUser information.
        return user;
      }).then(function(user){
        console.log("Logged in: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.email); //this also prints correct user email info.
        //signUpPhoneNumber and department declared elsewhere.
        logUser(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, signUpPhoneNumber, department);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
          alert('The password is too weak.');
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      });
```

I understand that the create user function should automatically sign in the user, and the currentUser isn’t null, yet somehow the permission keeps being denied (the database rules are the default rules of requiring authentication).

The security rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I also tested the sign-up callback and onAuthStateChanged callback and found that the auth state change fires after the sign-up callback, yet putting the database write in the onAuthStateChanged callback doesn't work when triggered from a sign-up. (It does work when triggered from a regular sign-in though).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant security rules. For testing, you might also want to set `".write": true` and see what it writes for `user.uid`.

Comment: My bad, the security rules are the default ones ( auth != null). As I’ve said, the function calls successfully when called from the sign-in callback, and it puts the user ID in the database under the users node with the correct info.

Comment: What version of firebase.js were you using? There were issues with version `4.5.2` where some of the auth permissions were not properly passed along. They should have been fixed in version `4.6.0`.

Comment: Hi! It was 4.5.2; I just noticed the 4.6.0 release in the config code; I'll be trying it soon

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Firebase 4.5.2. Updating to 4.6.0 worked.